# It is possible to paste a whole Class on JShell?

Tags: jshell

I would like to know if using the new command jshell, it is possible to test a whole Java class.

Many thanks in advance.

Juan antonio

Comment: Yes. Just try it.

Comment: It depends what the class contains.

Comment: Title asks if possible to *paste*. It's actually broken for some reason, only first 2 lines are pasted. But you can use command `/edit` to get an editor where you can paste a big snippet. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833901/multiline-paste-in-jshell) for details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline paste in jshell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41833901/multiline-paste-in-jshell)

Answer (score 0):

Use `/open` command to let JShell read the Java class as a snippet.

`/open C:\Test.java` should add contents of Test.java as a snippet.

A question on similar lines is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399338/how-to-run-a-whole-java-file-added-as-a-snippet-in-jshell)